# Caching issue with same classes througout different pages

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I am having some issues on a website built on Wordpress in combination with WP-rocket, although the build does not really matter in this case if I am not mistaken.

I have a class on a blogpage called `et_pb_section`which has an CSS background. However, this class is used on different pages as well, and - of course - the cached CSS is showing the background image here as well. I did not have this issue earlier strangely, but I am not even sure how this would work normally. CSS caching would be kinda useless if I need to make a seperate class for every background CSS class.

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

based on your description the css is doing what is expected. Since you use that class on several pages, each page containing that class will react the same way. What you might try is to put the page id class in your css before your actual class.

```
.postid-154 .et_pb_section
```

Off course the class postid-154 will be different in your situation. The exact class can be found in the developper console within the  tag.

Comment: Thanks! If I had any control in this I would have done this, however, the CSS is generated from a builder, which makes this impossible unfortunally :(